# Уникальные значения HashSet vs Distinct

Tags: c#

Замер скоростей поиска уникальных значений показал разницу в 2 раза

> HashSet (9976672): 1179
>
> Distinct(9976672): 2159

```
//Заполняем коллекцию
var l = new List<int>();
var rand = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000000; ++i)
    l.Add(rand.Next());
//Дублируем несколько значений в исходной коллекции
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
    l.Add(l.ElementAt(rand.Next(l.Count-1)));
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
//Замеряем скорость с HashSet
sw.Restart();
var list1 = (new HashSet<int>(l)).ToList();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"HashSet ({list1.Count}): {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
//Замеряем скорость с Distinct
sw.Restart();
var list2 = l.Distinct().ToList();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"Distinct({list2.Count}): {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

Выходит, что дистинктом пользоваться плохо?

Comment: Тут проблема не столько в Distinct, сколько в ToList.

Comment: @PavelMayorov прав, в первом случае HashSet знает сколько в нем элементов и создает List сразу нужной вместимости, во втором случае вы вызываете `IEnumerable.ToList()` и список начинает пересоздаваться тысячи раз

Comment: @АндрейNOP откуда тысячи? Всего-то два десятка раз...

Comment: Ну это я преувеличил, конечно. А вообще, внутри `Distinct` почти такой же самый `Set`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваше тестирование некорректно и в нем есть несколько проблем:

Во-первых, вы передаете в конструктор `HashSet` коллекцию, реализующую `ICollection`, у которой есть свойство `Count`, т. е. `HashSet` по сути знает сколько элементов ему предстоит разместить и он может [подготовиться к этому заранее](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,144).

Методы `Linq` же действуют лениво и берут из входной коллекции *всегда* по одному элементу. Соответственно, хештаблица, которая фактически создается внутри `Distinct`, просто не готова заранее к таким входным объемам и ей приходится периодически расширяться во время работы, но, с другой стороны, она и не должна быть готова к большим объемам, т. к. вы вполне можете написать `.Distinct().Take(10)` и усилия на выделение лишнего места будут потрачены впустую.

Во-вторых, в вашем коде аналогичная проблема с `.ToList()`, в первом случае вы вызываете его на экземпляре `ICollection`, во втором — на экземпляре `IEnumerable`.

Итого, если переписать ваш код так:

```
...
var list1 = (new HashSet<int>(l.Enumerate())).ToList(10000000);
...
var list2 = l.Enumerate().Distinct().ToList(10000000);
...
```

где:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Enumerate<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
            yield return item;
    }

    public static List<TSource> ToList<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int capacity)
    {
        var list = new List<TSource>(capacity);
        list.AddRange(source);
        return list;
    }
}
```

Результаты сближаются до пределов погрешности изменений:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А достаточно было бы заглянуть в [`Distinct`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,837) и заметить, что там используется самописный [`Set`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,572cb84955a529c2) с практически идентичной реализацией как в [`HashSet`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,188b8f94f8fc999b). То есть, по сути, вы мерили скорость одного и того же алгоритма

Comment: Я знаю, что там `Set`, но проблема-то здесь не в нем, а в окружении

Comment: Вы говорите про проблему измерений (это, кстати, сама по себе сложная задача - я бы лучше тулзу для этого юзал типа BenchmarkDotNet), а я говорю про то, что можно было и не мерить :)

Comment: Можно было бы не мерить — да, я бы и не стал. Но суть поста объяснить разницу в результатах замера. Насчет специальных фреймворков для тестирования полностью согласен.

Comment: с вами сложно спорить, особенно когда согласен с тем, что вы пишете :)